# What to do/throw when you have hit a API limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a API with a limit, there is a high possibility that I could hit the limit.

I am wondering how people handle this? Do they check if they hit the limit and then throw an exception? If so what type of exception?

Are there any best practices?

I am able to see if I hit the limit like below:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.error))
   {
       // we have hit a limit
   }
```

This API is used for a MVC application.
I am caching the `ActionResult` methods with the API content (`[OutputCache]`). If the Action method does not recieve the API result then the view will be empty, but if i throw something it will end up on the custom errors page.

Comment: This would entirely depend on the design of the process that consumes the API

Comment: The question is a bit broad as is and hard to answer.  Is this an API that's critical to the functioning of the application?  Can the user of your application do anything about this limit?

Comment: That is a fair point. In my example it is a MVC application. If the Api fails and the `ActionMethod` needs to refresh it's cache then It will use the API

Comment: I only use exceptions for lesser possibility issues and that is why I think it is an exception. For a high possibility error occurring, I would have to think a about a design to be fault-tolerant. Being a high possibility error, means you cannot put all your eggs in it.

Comment: I added more information

Comment: You always need to catch the exception at some point and deal with it, it's not aboud throwing exceptions and forget about them.

Comment: Thinking about it. I should really catch it higher up the stack and then deal with it (Possibly in a `BaseController`).

Comment: That's why it is so important to have a custom exception type. The most important thing about the exception is the type because you manage them based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first log what happened using the information you receive from result.error and then create a custom exception and throw it including the original error message.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.error))
{
     // we have hit a limit
     // log error
     // throw new MyException(result.error);
}
```

Normally you can't do much in this type of error so you log it, throw the exception and it's somebody's else problem. When the exception is caught, you could decide, based on the exception type, to wait and retry.

Comment: So just log an throw. Makes sense, just wondered how other people handle these situations.

Comment: I have updated my original post. It;s for a MVC application so waiting will hold up the UI thread.

Comment: In that case, you should not retry. You should dispaly a page explaining what happened to the user. If the action still has to be executed, you could do it in the background and inform the user that it will be done soon or something like that.